# How to set all programs and browsers zoom to 150%

Tags: browser, zoom

Sorry for bugging everyone i used to be able to do this myself before a brain injury.

I know there is register setting that determines that zoom is always at about 90% but because i can not remember any more I can not remember where to find this so i can change default zoom of programs to 150% and browser to 150% browser independent

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking about. On Windows 7 you could use the "Display" Dialog (Control Panel » Appearance and Personalization » Display or Persoanlize » DIsplay).

Comment: In Windows 10:
Right click on desktop, display settings
Move the top slider on display choice, "Change the size of text, apps and other items" to 150%, then everything will be zoomed.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortnally that only changevscreen soze but each app lime word etc when you open it reverts to default of 90% but the application menus etc are larger with both suggested ways but the text your typing and reading isnt. for browser you have to zoom in i want to set it permently to 150%. i cnt comment on my own thread which is daft

Comment: Why not simply reduce the resolution of your display?

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand because of the poor grammar/spelling. Please take a minute to edit it to make better sense. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed. I will downvote this. Give a reply when you've edited to a readable format and I'll change it to an upvote.